# Concatenate two sql fields using a select statement (sqlite)

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

error received: OperationalError: near "||": syntax error

```
sql= "Select FirstName  || " " ||  LastName AS Nominative from users"
```

Answer (score 1):

If using double quotes to denote your Python string, you'll need to use single quotes inside your SQL query:

```
sql = "Select FirstName  || ' ' ||  LastName AS Nominative from users"
```

Usually I use the multi-line quote syntax when including raw SQL in a Python script:

```
sql = """
      Select FirstName  || ' ' ||  LastName AS Nominative 
      from users
      """
```

That means you can use either double or single quotes inside your query, and also makes more complex queries than the one you've posted more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> sql= "Select FirstName  || " " ||  LastName AS Nominative from users"
>>> sql
'Select FirstName  ||  ||  LastName AS Nominative from users'
```

The double quote are Python's string delimiters, so you have *two* strings, which are simply concatenated by Python.

You could escape them as `\"`, but in any case, SQL uses single quotes for strings:

```
sql = "Select FirstName || ' ' ||  LastName AS Nominative from users"
```